# How does the range of districts work?

Tags: civilization-6

How does the 6 tile range zone looks like? Does that mean 6 hex "steps" away from the district, or any city center within the six "rings" of the district?

Comment: Any city centre within the district's 6 tile range will be affected by any buildings who specifically mentions sharing bonuses to other cities.